# Least number of polygons to cover vector in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, line, overlapping-features

I have two layers :

1. Polygon rectangles layer representing different footprints
2. Line layer representing roads

[image]

I want to know what is the least number of polygons from the polygon layer do I need to cover the roads layer, meaning basically to remove any polygons that covers the same area as other polygons in its layer. I don't care which one will be deleted and which one will remain, as long only 1 remains per for a certain area.

Another image with opacity[image]

Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: Do I understand correctly that your polygons are overlapping (it is not clearly visible in the screenshot)? If yes - you wrote that only 1 should remain for any given area - but are you sure it is possible? Could you provide a screenshot with a bit of transparency, so that we can see how exactly your polygons are shaped?

Comment: I'll add to the original post an image with an opacity and more clear boundaries. Regarding your question - Yes, they are overlapping but not in the exact same location, they are not identical.

Comment: Very interesting question. Unfortunately, I don't have a soution, but some ideas how you could begin: 1) select all polygons that are intersected by a road, delete all others 2) from the remaining, group polygons together that intersect 3) calculate the length of the road segment inside each polygon and keep for each group the polygon that has the longest line. However, there will be gaps in between. As I sayed: I don't have a solution, just a few ideas to start thinking...